# How fix windows 10 darker screen after last update (version is 1709)?

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display

I have exactly the same problem as described [here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/id-3551028/darker-display-latest-windows-update-fixed-settings.html)

> Exactly the same, afte update to 1709 version of Windows 10, on start up the screen is normal, then after a couple of seconds it goes dark and also the defininition and resolution of the images seem to be worst.

But I have no NVidia or AMD video card. I have Pentium G4600 with Intel HD Graphics 630. I have updated drivers for last version but it does not help.

For my personal opinion it is a pure software problem which should solved by turning something off. But what? have anybody fixed this?

**System**

- Windows 10 version 1709
- Monitor LG 27UD58 4k viaconnected via display port

**UPDATED**

[Here](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/display-colors-change-after-installing-fall/8a235d25-5aaa-4122-8180-4b12efc8a9eb) is discussion about G4600 and 1709 updated. The "best" answer is downgrade to previos version but rolling back to previous windows version definitely leads to more problem then dark colors.

**Notes**

- it is **not** disaply problem, display brightness and contrast did not change.
- the is **not** about calibration - because colors are changed at start up just aftre couple of seconds
- the problem about collors **not** turning monitor off (a lot of similar questions about that)

Comment: Check your power management settings.

Comment: adaptive Brightness is turned off.

Comment: Can you change the brightness settings at all, and if so, what happens if you change them, like setting it darker then brighter? This option is only available for laptops, but given that you did not make any mention of it, I just have to assume things here.

Comment: Thanks but I have desktop :(

Comment: Is the "night light" enabled? https://www.howtogeek.com/302186/how-to-enable-night-light-on-windows-10/